# How to Call .pl File inside .cgi Script

Tags: perl, pdf, cgi, perl-module

i am using getpdftext.pl from CAM::PDF to extract pdf and print it to text, but in my web application i want to call this getpdftext.pl inside .cgi script. Can u suggest me as to what to do or how to proceed ahead. i tried converting getpdftext.pl to getpdftext.cgi but it doesnt work.

Thanks all

this is a extract from my request_admin.cgi script

```
my $filename  = $q->param('quote');
:
:
:
&parsePdf($filename);

#function to extract text from pdf ,save it in a text file and parse the required fields
sub parsePdf($)
{
    my $i;
    print $_[0];
    $filein = "quote_uploads/$_[0]";
    $fileout = 'output.txt';

    print "inside parsePdf\n";

    open OUT, ">$fileout" or die "error: $!";

    open IN, '-|', "getpdftext.pl $filein" or die "error :$!" ;

    while(<IN>)
    {
        print "$i";
        $i++;
        print OUT;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean `open IN, '-|', "perl getpdftext.pl $filein" or die "error :$!";`?

Comment: yes jack..i am referring to "perl getdpftext.pl $filein"

Comment: i am getting the following error: Permission denied at /request_admin.cgi line 301, <fh00001C%3A\\Users\\Desktop\\quote.pdf> line 414., referer http://abc.com/adminForm.html                   Line 301: open OUT, ">$fileout" or die "error: $!";

Comment: In that case, you'll need to allow the web server to access the file.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly likely that

- Your CGI script's environment isn't complete enough to locate
  `getpdftext.pl` and/or
- The web-server user doesn't have permission to execute it anyway

Have a look in your web-server's error-log and see if it is reporting any pointers as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: thanks a lot RET, the error is in `open OUT, ">$fileout" or die "error: $!";` getting Permission denied error, the file exists, what should i do

Comment: For a start, make sure the getpdftext.pl script is executable by anyone, and change the CGI script to call it using its full, absolute path

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, it might be simpler and more direct to use [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CAM%3a%3aPDF) directly, which should have been installed along with `getpdftext.pl` anyway.

I had a look at this script and I think that your `parsePdf` sub could just as easily be written as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use CAM::PDF;

sub parsePdf {
    my $filein = "quote_uploads/$_[0]";
    my $fileout = 'output.txt';

    open my $out_fh, ">$fileout" or die "error: $!";

    my $doc = CAM::PDF->new($filein) || die "$CAM::PDF::errstr\n";
    my $i = 0;

    foreach my $p ($doc->rangeToArray(1,$doc->numPages()))
    {
        my $str = $doc->getPageText($p);
        if (defined $str)
        {
            CAM::PDF->asciify(\$str);
            print $i++;
            print $out_fh $str;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, vl try this way,  found the error in my program but unable to debug, its in                                               `open OUT, ">$fileout" or die "error: $!";`

Comment: @sandyutd: that's a permissions problem in trying to write $fileout in the current directory. Change $fileout to `$ENV{TEMPDIR}/output.txt`, although even that isn't much good - it certainly won't support concurrent requests - but it will at least get you moving forward. Ultimately, you'll need to ensure every request uses its own unique temporary file, ie `$ENV{TEMPDIR}/output-$$.txt` ($$ equates to the PID of the CGI process).

Comment: @sandyutd - if it suits, you could also write debug output to STDERR, then view it in the apache logs